# Dynamic select with default selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

How could I generate a select element with options and default option mark as 'selected'?

For example, my options array:

```
    $scope.options = [
        {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "One",
            "selected": true
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "label": "Two"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "label": "Three"
        }
    ];
```

And the angular html:

```
<select name="">
    <option ng-repeat=" option in options " value="{{ option.value }}" ng-selected=" option.selected === true "> {{ option.label }}</option>
</select>
```

So, I need to generate something like this:

```
<select name="">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I want use `ng-options`.

Thanks

Comment: what are going to do when an option is selected? will it be set to an object?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of complex object using **ng-options** is better option. So you could do it with this code.

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="yourModel">
</select>
```

I only add **ng-model** it is required for ng-options to work, just set your model the value you want it will be automatically set up...

Comment: you need to remove options if you set it in ng-options

Comment: I tried something similar, but ng-model didn't will update the flag selected.

Comment: ng-repeat with ng-options?? I don't think this is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="selectedOpt" ng-options="option.value for option in options" ng-change="setOption(selectedOpt)">
```

In you controller, you should set the model to be the one that is selected

```
$scope.selectedOpt = _.find($scope.options, function(o){return o.selected;})

function setOption(opt){
    opt.selected =true;
}
```

Comment: You need to clear the others options. Look for content of {{ options }} after any click. But is a good approach!

Comment: This dont set default `selected`

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo  I didn't write the exact code. but the idea is there.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen what part doesn't work? I used underscore.js in the code. Is it possible that you don't have that and its not working?

Comment: I don't use underscore I only talk about angular.

Comment: so use angular filters to filter the selected object

Answer (score 0):

To have a default option the list must be populated first, otherwise you will get errors or a blank option. You can do this in your controller. Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rosstroha/3dcthfwh/3/

**Example Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.optionList = [
    {value: "val1"},
    {value: "val2"}
    ]
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.optionList[0];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.value for option in optionList">
  </div>
</div>
```

Optionally you can add another option that will always be there like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.value for option in optionList">
    <option disabled value="">Select</option>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And, my own default selected value??

Comment: It's not really clear as to what you mean by "my own default selected value". You can have whatever value you want show up as the selected one when you set `$scope.selectedOption` to _your own default selected value_ inside the controller.